# How to include source code for IAR builtin libraries(c runtime etc) while jtag debugging

Tags: linker, initialization, iar, stm32f4discovery, jtag

I'm new to IAR EWARM 8.2.22. I've got a STM32MF4 disco board. I want to single step through the initialization code. But it takes me to the code provided by IAR builtin library(c runtime setup).

Is it possible to include the sources for this code while debugging ?

I've looked around but could not find the answer.

Cheers
Ritu

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the ability to do this depends upon the licence that you have for the Embedded Workbench product that you are using.  In order to see the library source code you need to have a full paid licence.  The library source code is not included in the free evaluation versions as stated on this [IAR web page](https://www.iar.com/iar-embedded-workbench/#!?currentTab=free-trials).

It has been some time since I used this software but I believe that if you have a suitable licence then you will be prompted to install the library code when you start Workbench.

Comment: This does not really help since the shipped libraries do not contain debug information.

Comment: @Johan If you have the full licenced version that comes with the source code then you do have the debug information.  I have single stepped through the functions.